# Kendo Line Chart - Datasource from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've problem to plot data into line chart. There is nothing appear accept label. My data from json file.

Here is my json file format:

```
[{
    "country": "India",
    "value": [
        ​3.907,
        ​7.943,
        ​7.848,
        ​6.284,
        ​7.263
    ]
},{
    "country": "World",
    "value": [
        ​1.988,
        ​2.733,
        ​3.994,
        ​3.464,
        ​4.001
    ]
}]
```

And here is my jquery. In series part, I've put data as "value". Is it wrong?? Hopefully someone can help me...
Thanks in advance.

```
function createChart() {
 var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "country.JSON", dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
  });

        $j("#chart_div").kendoChart({
            dataSource: ds,
            title: {
                text: "Gross domestic product growth"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line",
                style: "smooth"
            },
            series:  [{
                data: "value",
                name: "India"
            }, {
                field: "value",
                name: "World"
            }, {
                field: "value",
                name: "Russia"
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}%"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code below shows the way to pass the json data to the createChart function for creating a Kendo Line chart

```
 

    function createChart() {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    title: {
                        text: "Gross domestic product growth"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    chartArea: {
                        background: ""
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "line",
                        style: "smooth"
                    },
                    series: [{
                    "country": "India",
                     "value": [ ​3.907,​7.943,​7.848, ​6.284,​7.263]
                    },{
                    "country": "World",
                     "value": [​1.988,​2.733,​3.994,​3.464,​4.001]
                    }],
                    valueAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}%"
                        },
                        line: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        axisCrossingValue: -10
                    },
                    categoryAxis: {
                        categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
                        majorGridLines: {
                            visible: false
                        },
                        labels: {
                            rotation: "auto"
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}%",
                        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(createChart);
```